# Which Red Hat version i need to prepare for red hat exams?

Tags: redhat

Which Red Hat version i need to prepare for red hat exams?

(maybe centos anough )

Thanks

Comment: http://www.redhat.com/certification/faq/#six http://www.redhat.com/certification/rhce/objectives/ -- `This guide provides information candidates may use in preparing to take the Red Hat Certified Engineer (RHCE) exam on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6`.

Comment: red hat have version for desktop/server/virtual - which version do i need?

Answer (score 1):

There was a brief changeover period where RHEL5 exams were still being taken but all courses and exams should now be happening on RHEL6.

As you may be aware there is not yet a CentOS 6. You can however go to redhat.com and sign up for RHN to download a trial/evaluation copy of RHEL6. I believe these are time limited, or at least the support for them and ability to get updates is.

Comment: its different version of RHEL, I asking which version do i need? like: Red Hat Enterprise Linux for Desktops////Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 1/2/4 socket////Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization for Servers Starter Kit